# Bulk API 2.0 and Attachments Upload

Tags: attachment, bulk-api, bulk, bulk-api-v2

Does Bulk API 2.0 support Attachment upload related to Account (for example)?
I checked the documentation and it shows Binary attachment upload using Bulk API and not V2.0.

Reference link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/binary_intro.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman API - Attachment is not a supported object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404162/postman-api-attachment-is-not-a-supported-object)